# Unable to figure out the index error code - Python

Tags: python

```
import random

line_count = 0
for line in file:
    line_count = line_count + 1

line_count = line_count - 1
print(line_count)
randomLine = random.randrange(0, line_count)
print(randomLine)

lines = file.readlines()
print(lines[randomLine])
```

I checked what is needed with trying to cancel the index error code, I reduced the line value by 1 so it wont try and print a non existent line. I do not know what is wrong with the code.

This is the input file

```
Line 16 - 5x - 5 = 20
Line 17 - 5
Line 18 - 1x + 5 = 10
Line 19 - 5
```

Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Liq04\Desktop\SDD Python\python_project_enhanced_v2.py", line 252, in <module>
    mainscreen()
  File "c:\Users\Liq04\Desktop\SDD Python\python_project_enhanced_v2.py", line 242, in mainscreen
    main_menu()
  File "c:\Users\Liq04\Desktop\SDD Python\python_project_enhanced_v2.py", line 210, in main_menu
    quiz1()
  File "c:\Users\Liq04\Desktop\SDD Python\python_project_enhanced_v2.py", line 158, in quiz1
    quiz2()
  File "c:\Users\Liq04\Desktop\SDD Python\python_project_enhanced_v2.py", line 121, in quiz2
    print(lines[randomLine])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please add the error stack!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the after the `for` loop below completes, the `file` pointer reaches to the end of the file and so `file.readlines()` return an empty list.

```
for line in file:
```

You can reset the `file` pointer to start reading from the start again using `seek()` method:

```
file.seek(0)
```

The complete code would be:

```
file = open('Odata.txt', 'r')
line_count = 0
for line in file:
    line_count = line_count + 1

line_count = line_count - 1
print(line_count)

import random
randomLine = None
randomLine = random.randrange(0, line_count)
print(randomLine)

file.seek(0)
lines = file.readlines()
print(lines[randomLine])

file.close()
```

---

Update: As rightly pointed by @SpaceBurger, you don't need most of the above stuff and can simply get the lines count using `len(file.readlines())`.

Here is the updated code:

```
import random
with open('Odata.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    line_count = len(lines)
    randomLine = random.randrange(0, line_count)
    print(lines[randomLine])
```

Opening the file using the context manager `with` will automagically close the file when it comes out of the `with` block.

Comment: One could also store the content of `lines = file.readlines()` then count the number of lines with `len(lines)`. This would remove the need to use `file.seek(0)` because we can simply use the `lines` variable.

Comment: this will not work after we have iterated over the loop since `file.readlines()` would return an empty list. I assume you meant to save it before the loop.

Comment: Yes, I was too late to edit my comment. Using `len(lines)` would also remove the need for the 4 or 5 lines of code dedicated to counting the number of lines.

Comment: I agree most of it is not required and can be done in one line as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you're moving the file pointer to the end in while counting lines
write this code before reading line

```
# file.seek(0) moves the pointer to the starting position

import random

file=open("./test.text","r")
line_count = 0
for line in file:
    line_count = line_count + 1

line_count = line_count - 1
print("line count",line_count)
randomLine = random.randrange(0, line_count)
print("random number",randomLine)
file.seek(0)
print(file.read())
```